# Char vs int calling conventions

Tags: c, ocaml, calling-convention

Are there any 32- or 64- bit platforms on which a `int8_t`, `int16_t`, and `int32_t` are passed differently?

I am asking because OCaml (4.03+, which has not yet been released) can pass 32- or 64- bit integers and doubles to C directly, but not 8- or 16- bit integers or single-precision floats.

Edit: Basically I am asking if

`char x(char y)`

can be called as

`int x(int y)`

Comment: I can't imagine any calling convention on any architecture would allow for that in any modern system. For register-based calling conventions, each argument is put in a register. I wouldn't expect any compiler to try to allocate parts of a register, it's all or nothing. That would probably be horribly inefficient anyway.  For stack-based, you're pushing the arguments in word-sized chunks typically, otherwise they risk misalignment. And again, very inefficient.

Comment: @JeffMercado: Not that it is related to this question, but when passing certain structs, the compiler will indeed allocate "parts of registers" to struct fields. For instance, a `struct {int a, b;}` will be passed in one reigster on AMD64, one half of the register being used for each field.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword in calling convention is convention and conventions differ for many reasons ie architecture etc. I might be using a `int8_t` but behind the scenes it may be taking up `32` bits of space or on 64bit systems `64` bits. As long as it behaves like an `int8_t` I don't care. A language might expose a `char` but it might be represented as an int, C does this. When you dig into the C interface for languages at a much higher level of abstraction than `C` you start to see some design decisions the compiler writers made to simplify their lives.

Answer (score 1):

Even *if* there were 32- or 64-bit platform that pass `int8_t`s, `int16_t`s and `int32_t`s differently (which I doubt there are, for various reasons), that would not be an excuse for OCaml to not be able to pass such arguments. All it would have to do is follow the platform's standard ABI and the world would be alright. In all likelihood, the FFI simply doesn't implement it because it wasn't sufficiently useful for the implementers.

That being said, one main reason why you would be very unlikely to find such a platform is because most C compilers try to preserve some, at least token, compatibility with K&R C, where it was not necessary to declare function prototypes; undeclared functions will be called as if they had `int` arguments and return values. For such reasons, virtually all ABIs always promote all integer arguments to the native word size, so that they will be assignment-compatible with whatever concrete integer type is in fact used, even if it would be possible to pass the argument more efficiently using smaller units.

**EDIT:** To answer your edited question, then on all somewhat standard ABIs, yes, you can call `char x(char)` as an `int x(int)`. One caveat could be, however, that a compiler may assume the higher-order bits of the passed word are zero, however, so that you may, potentially, get undefined behavior if you, for example, pass `512` as an argument that is used as a `char` in the C function.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any 32- or 64- bit platforms on which a int8_t, int16_t, and int32_t are passed differently?

Presumably there exists one, maybe experimental or historical. But if we limit our domain of discourse to the set of architectures supported by the OCaml system (the main implementation), then the answer is no.

> I am asking because OCaml (4.03+, which has not yet been released) can
>   pass 32- or 64- bit integers and doubles to C directly, but not 8- or
>   16- bit integers or single-precision floats.

The reason is because OCaml has a different representation of an integer. In comparison with the C representation, it is shifted to the left by one bit and incremented. So `0` is represented as C's `1`, `1` is `3` and so on. The least significant bit is used to distinguish between immediate values and pointers. So OCaml integer effectively has one less bit, i.e., 63 bits on 64-bit system and 31 on 32-bit system. That all means that, before passing an integer to a c function you need to shift it to the right. A simple and low cost operation. The `char` type is also represented by `int`, so it has the same issue. There are no `int8_t` and `int16_t` in the standard library, so I can't speak about them. A third-party library may introduce them in any representation, that may or may not support the direct passing to a C function.

OCaml's `int32`, `int64`, `nativeint` and `float`, are all represented as a boxed value, i.e., they are allocated in OCaml's heap and passed around OCaml functions as a pointer. The representation of the allocated block is the same as in `C`, thus allowing to pass it as is. Of course, this is safe only if a called function doesn't store this value somewhere and doesn't call any functions that may provoke a garbage collection. Before 4.03 a programmer was required to unbox the value, by either copying the contents into C variable (safe way), or by dereferencing and passing it directly (a dangerous way - you should know what you're doing). The 4.03 release provides a new annotation (an attribute `unboxed`), that is a generalization of the previously existed `"%float"` annotation. This annotation allows to pass values of this specific four types directly. This annotation works for a restricted set of function types, and, of course, is safe only for specific functions.

So, to summarize, small integers, are passed to C in a very fast manner. Boxed values, usually require some extra work, that also introduces a call to garbage collection and allocation. To alleviate this, 4.03 added some optimizations that allow passing them directly, if it is safe.

> Edit: Basically I am asking if
>
> `char x(char y)`
>
> can be called as
>
> `int x(int y)`

From the OCaml foreign function interface point of view there is no big difference. The only problem, is that OCaml `int` is smaller, than C `int`, so if `x` may return a value, that doesn't fit into the OCaml representation, a bigger (and boxed) type should be used, like `nativeint` for example. In many cases this issue can be ignored, e.g., when `int` is an error code, or it is known to be small, or no greater than the input parameter.